# What is the correct way to romanize ッジ?

Tags: rōmaji, gemination

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hepburn_romanization#Double_consonants), ッチ is rendered as *tch*, not *cch* (etchi not ecchi). Logically I would think that ッジ would then be *dj* but there's no example of it. What is the correct way? *dj* or *jj*? Is there any comprehensive guide to Hepburn romanization that helps with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK `cch => tch` is the *only* exception defined in the Hepburn romanization system and its variants (such as [パスポート式](http://www.hyogo-passport.jp/main/hebon.html)). All the other 促音 (`っ`) are expressed by repeating the same consonant. Specifically, I'm not aware of any romanization standard which uses `dj`. So if you want to strictly obey the rule, バッジ would be rendered as *bajji* even in the Hepburn system which is thought to be closer to English pronunciation. In [訓令式](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kunrei-shiki_romanization) this would be *bazzi*. IMEs accept both.

Traditional Japanese words occasionally have っち (eg, 八丁堀【はっちょうぼり】, 坊っちゃん, 湿地【しっち】), but probably there's no word that contains っじ/っぢ. Perhaps that's why there isn't any standard. There are many katakana combinations which are used to write loanwords but are not strictly defined in the traditional romanization systems (eg, ツァ, ティ, ドゥ). They are not suitable for writing non-Japanese-origin words in the first place.

Comment: For what it's worth, some people (myself included) don't like this aspect of these systems and will choose to always use a double consonant for geminate consonant (sokuon).

Comment: If that's what you really like, エッチ would be *echchi, not ecchi.